# AJAX Datatables filtering with empty associations in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, datatable

I am using the `ajax-datatables-rails` gem to generate a server-side processed datatable.  My datatable class looks something like this:

```
class StoreDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base

  def view_columns
    @view_columns ||= {
      id: {source: "Store.id"},
      name: {source: "Store.name"},
      item_qty: {source: "Item.qty"},
      item_name: {source: "Item.name"},
    }
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record| {
      id: record.id,
      name: record.name,
      item_qty: record.item.try(:qty),
      item_name: record.item.try(:name),
    }
    end
  end

  private

  def get_raw_records
    Store.includes(:item).all
  end

end
```

My database models look like this:

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :item
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: store
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: StoreDatatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end
```

And my coffee script for my datatables looks like this:

```
$('#store').dataTable
  processing: true
  serverSide: true
  searching: true
  lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 100]
  ajax: $('#store').data('source')
  columns: [
    {data: 'id'}
    {data: 'name'}
    {data: 'item_qty',
    defaultContent: ""},
    {data: 'item_name',
    defaultContent: ""},
  ]
  deferRender: true
```

I can display the table just fine, but when I go to try and filter results of the table, I am getting errors due to empty associations.  Not all `Stores` will necessarily have `Items`, but I need to be able to display all `Stores` regardless if they have `Items` or not (which is why I use `includes` instead of a `joins` in my `get_raw_records` method).

The error I get in Rails when I attempt to filter results is:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'item.qty' in 'where clause'`

How can I have the datatable's filter working with empty associations?  The associations need to be searchable.

I am using Rails 5.1.2, Ruby 2.4.1, with the latest Datatables release (including the gem).

Comment: I've never used this gem, but what happens if you add `references(:item)` to your `get_raw_records`? "For SQL-fragments you need to use references to force joined tables" ([from the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations))

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) when talking about using `where` conditions with `includes`:

> Using `where` like this will only work when you pass it a Hash. For SQL-fragments you need to use `references` to force joined tables

So you may need to add `references(:item) to`get_raw_records` to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I got a range filter to work like this:

in the datatable view I created a table above the datatable to input the range variables, then add some javascript to reload the datatable on change:

```
          <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Minimum CWD:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="minCWD" name="minCWD"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Maximum CWD:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="maxCWD" name="maxCWD"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {             
            // other options
            var table = $('#example').DataTable()
                    
            $("#minCWD").change(function () {
              table.ajax.reload();
            });
            $("#maxCWD").change(function() {
              table.ajax.reload();
            });
        });
</script>
```

then to add the filter variables to the ajax call (in the coffee file):

```
ajax: {
      url: $('#example').data('source'),
      beforeSend: (xhr) => xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
      data: (d) ->
        $.extend {}, d, 'minCWD': $('#minCWD').val(),
        $.extend {}, d, 'maxCWD': $('#maxCWD').val()
    }
// note: the beforeSend may not be required
```

then add a filter in the model_datatable.rb:

```
def get_raw_records
    #YOUR TYPICAL SELECTION...note: I'm using AREL and joining schools with pstats
    #now filter by your max min variables
    if params['minCWD'].present?
      schools = schools.where(pstats[:cwd_percent].gteq(params['minCWD']))
    end
    if params['maxCWD'].present?
      schools = schools.where(pstats[:cwd_percent].lteq(params['maxCWD']))
    end
    return schools
  end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: ExampleDatatable.new(params, view_context: view_context) }
end
```

working example here: https://schoolsparrow.com/arizona/schools